# Calculate elapsed time in milliseconds using Go

Tags: go, logging, time

I'm using the following code (Go version 1.12) to log elapsed time:

```
package time

func Elapsed() func() {
    start := time.Now()
    return func() {
        log.Debugf("Call took %v", time.Since(start))
    }
}
```

This normally works fine for ms:

> "elapsed":"945.714448ms"

However, it changes from ms to s if it's above 1 second:

> "elapsed":"3.577901569s"

How do I force it to always log in milliseconds?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Milliseconds()](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=21679:21698#L790) on the [Duration](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) that is returned from `Since()`:

```
log.Debugf("Call took %vms", time.Since(start).Milliseconds())
```

Note that this does not add the unit (in case you need it).

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'm getting this error: `time.Since(start).Milliseconds undefined (type time.Duration has no field or method Milliseconds)`. Or was this added with 1.13?

Comment: @ArSeN, impossible. cause Duration is int64  which is not a struct. https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration which is nanoseconds.  `time.Since(start) / 1000000` should work. https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-how-to-get-time-in-milliseconds

Comment: time.Duration.Milliseconds was added March 2019. Update you Go version now.

Comment: Thanks, looks like my environment didn't properly update to 1.13, I see it now. :)